# Input time save hour and minute in separate ids

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

Is it possible to use input type="time" to send separate information?

Example hour to id="hour" minute to id="minute"

I have code in which I would need this function.

It would be something like scheduling a function in the system.
Hour and minute.

```
if($dados_agendamento["frequencia"] == "1") {
    $descricao = "".
                $lang['lang_info_gerenciador_agendamentos_info_frequencia1']
                ." ".$data
                ." ".$dados_agendamento["hora"]
                .":".$dados_agendamento["minuto"]."";

} elseif($dados_agendamento["frequencia"] == "2") {
    $descricao = "".
                $lang['lang_info_gerenciador_agendamentos_info_frequencia2']
                ." ".
                $dados_agendamento["hora"]
                .":".
                $dados_agendamento["minuto"]."";
```

```
$descricao = "".
            ucfirst($dados_acao["acao"])
            ." ".
            substr($lista_dias, 0, -2)
            ." ".
            $dados_acao["hora"]
            .":".
            $dados_acao["minuto"]
            ." ".
            $playlist."";
```

The hour and minute information is stored in the bank if anyone can help

[image]

Comment: You'd have to split the string it sends you

Comment: I managed to solve it, thank you